# Populating Data Table in Word with Excel VBA: Selecting Range between two bookmarks and pasting

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

With Excel and Word 2013 & Windows 8:

In essence, I have an excel template that I want to update to a word template. I have about 20 tables in Word, that are preformatted and I want to update those columns from their corresponding columns in excel, but had a very hard time working with vba and word tables.

Trying to copy a range in Excel, select the corresponding range in Word by selecting between two bookmarks, and paste the data. **I receive a Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method**

I realize this is probably not an ideal strategy for accomplishing this task, so if you can suggest a better strategy with code, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
Sub PopulateColumninWord()

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Document

Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument

Set rngStart = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Start").Range
Set rngEnd = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("End").Range

ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C19").Select
Selection.Copy

With wdDoc
    .Range(rngStart.Start, rngEnd.End).Select
    .PasteAndFormat
End With

Set wdApp = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you running this code in Excel or Word? Not exactly sure what you mean by *"I have an excel template that I want to update to a word template"*. Have you tried to paste the column as a link into Word so when the column is updated in Excel, it can be refreshed in Word?

Comment: @CharlieRB His code runs in Excel. And a Word instance is open and referenced from within Excel VBA. The Word doc has 2 bookmarks named `start` and `end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example will copy the cells `A1:A2` from Excel to Word

### Using [bookmarks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-delete-bookmarks-f68d781f-0150-4583-a90e-a4009d99c2a0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

```
Sub PopulateColumninWord()

    Dim wdApp  As Object
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument

    'Read in position of two bookmarks named START and END
    Set rngStart = wdDoc.Bookmarks("Start").Range
    Set rngEnd = wdDoc.Bookmarks("End").Range

    'Copy range from Excel to Word
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A2").Copy
    wdDoc.Range(rngStart.End + 1, rngEnd.Start - 1).PasteAndFormat (22)

    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

### Using tables in Word

```
Sub PopulateColumninWord()

    Dim wdApp  As Object
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.ActiveDocument

    'Copy range from Excel to Word
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A2").Copy
    wdDoc.Range(wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Start, _
                wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.End).PasteAndFormat (22)

    'Copy single cell from Excel to Word
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Copy
    wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.PasteAndFormat (22)

    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

### Useful further links

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844915(v=office.15).aspx
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Word/SelectingaRangeofCells.htm

Comment: slight problem. I'm trying to populate a preformatted table in word. In this instance, It's a 3 column table, with the bookmarks in Cell C1 & C18. I want to fill in the third column. When running this macro, it replaces all the cells in the table. Is there a better way than using bookmarks to update entire columns?

Comment: @Capacete Could you please upload a Excel and Word example file at [www.ge.tt](http://ge.tt/) and share the link?

Comment: Here's the link: http://ge.tt/47OhFd62?c

Comment: @Capacete I didn't realize you're using tables. Since that, its much easier to target a specific *cell* in Word. All you need to know is the correct table name or number and what cells are there

Comment: AAAMMAZING!!!! I knew it was so easy, I was running into some stupid problem with pasting into the tables before. WHATEVER, THANK YOU!!!!!!

Comment: I'm having a problem with the formatting of some of the tables after running the macro. When the Xs are pasted into the word table, I have to click delete once in order for the character to be visible. It's almost as if there is a tabbed indentation for each pasted cell. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Capacete I tried your Word doc an reproduced the issue. Then, in a new Word doc I inserted a simple doc and resized the complete table to a small width. With that table, it worked and no cells were resized or content invisible. Can you verify this?

Comment: I uploaded 2 new files as it's happening with differently constructed tables. http://ge.tt/51iYS972?c

Comment: @Capacete This is no VBA issue. If you copy the 12 excel cells by hand and go to Word, insert them and choose `text only` you'll see the same odd behavior. But again, if you set up a fresh word and insert 1 table with 12x3 cells and don't format anything in that Word doc, you'll see that the macro runs fine. It has to do something with formatting in Word. Suggestion: Change only one Word table format property at a time and rerun the macro, check if everything went well. Change the next property, rerun macro and so on. I don't have more ideas

Comment: It was the hanging indent! Just had to remove it